# Simple stateful nn Keras, can fit model but not predict

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm

I'm trying to create a simple stateful neural network in keras to wrap my head around how to connect Embedding layers and LSTM's. I have a piece of text where I have mapped every character to a integer and would like to send in one character at a time to predict the next character. I have done this earlier where I have sent in 8 characters at a time and got that to work well (using `return_sequences=True` and `TimeDistributed(Dense)`). But this time I want to only send in 1 character at a time and this is where my problem arises.

The code I use to set up my model:

```
n_fac = 32
vocab_size = len(chars)
n_hidden = 256
batch_size=64

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size,n_fac,input_length=1,batch_input_shape=(batch_size,1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LSTM(n_hidden,stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size,activation='softmax'))
```

model.summary() gives me the following:

```
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     

embedding_1 (Embedding)          (64, 1, 32)           992         embedding_input_1[0][0]          

batchnormalization_1 (BatchNorma (64, 1, 32)           128         embedding_1[0][0]                

lstm_1 (LSTM)                    (64, 256)             295936      batchnormalization_1[0][0]       

dense_1 (Dense)                  (64, 31)              7967        lstm_1[0][0]                     

Total params: 305,023
Trainable params: 304,959
Non-trainable params: 64
```

---

The code I use to set up my training data:

```
text = ... #Omitted for simplicity. Just setting text to some kind of literature work

text = text.lower() #Simple model, therefor only using lower case characters

idx2char = list(set(list(text)))
char2idx = {char:idx for idx,char in enumerate(idx2char)}

text_in_idx = [char2idx[char] for char in text]

x = text_idx[:-1]
y = text_idx[1:]
```

---

Compiling and training my network:

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4),loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')

nb_epoch = 10
for i in range(nb_epoch):
    model.reset_states()
    model.fit(x,y,nb_epoch=1,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=False)
```

Training works as it should, the loss is reduced with each epoch.

Now I want to try out my trained network but have no idea how to give it a character to predict the next. I start out by resetting its states and then want to start feeding it one char at a time.

I tried a couple of different inputs but all of them failed. These are not qualified guesses.

```
#The model uses integers for characters, therefor integers are sent as input

model.predict([1]) #Type error

model.predict(np.array([1])) #Value error

model.predict(np.array([1])[np.newaxis,:]) #Value error

model.predict(np.array([1])[:,np.newaxis]) #Value error
```

Am I forced to send in something of length batch_size or how am I supposed to send in data for the model to predict something?

The error text for Value error is very long and obscure so I omitted it. I can supply it if needed.

Using theano backend with keras.

Comment: You need to specify the actual error, my guess is the data you are providing has the wrong shape.

Comment: Try `batch_input_shape=(None, 1)` in your first layer.

Comment: @grovina getting an error when that is done, the error is the following: `ValueError: If a RNN is stateful, a complete input_shape must be provided (including batch size).`

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro That is my problem, I dont know what shape it wants my data in. I want to build a model that takes 1 character index and outputs a prediction of what the next character should be. Heres my value error for one of the shapes I tried on my prediction data: `ValueError: dimension mismatch in args to gemm (64,256)x(256,256)->(32,256)`

Comment: @user3537014 what about `model.predict(np.ones(model.input_shape))`? Does it work?

Comment: To get it to work I have to set batch_size in model.predict() to my training batch_size. This defeats the purpose of taking 1 input at a time and I have to do more exploring to understand stateful model setup in keras. I have put this aside for now as I dont have enough free time to spend hours and hours on this problem. Thanks for trying to help out!